# How do I find my home in Minecraft after recovering corrupted saved world data?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Help please. Our computer crashed and the world where my son had built his house vanished. I followed instructions I found on minecraft.gamepedia.com for recovering corrupted saved world data - replacing the following with ones from a new world - 
level.dat
level.dat_mcr (not always present)
level.dat_old
session.lock

This seemed to work but we couldn't find the houses we'd built or the lava pillar we built to mark the spot. We've flown around in all directions for long distances and found nothing. I didn't know about F3 and coordinates before we lost the world so we don't have any for our houses. There are beds in the houses but I'm not sure if we ever slept in them as we couldn't figure out how that worked and we're in creative mode.

Is there any way to get the coordinates for our houses from the saved files for the world? Sorry if this question is not asked well - I'm a bit lost in this stuff but trying to recover it for my young son.

Comment: Forgot to say we're playing Minecraft on Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Try using MC-Edit, I haven't used it in a longtime, but there are filters where you can see only certain blocks. Change that to something you used to build with, such as wood. Also, keep in mind that your character usually spawns near x: 0, y: 64, z: 0.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We had a go with MCEdit and searched for bookshelf blocks and lapis lazuli blocks which were in the houses. We went to the coordinates - up in the 7 and 8000s X, so a long way from the spawn point, and there were no buildings and nothing that looked familiar.

Answer (score -1):

Do you or your son know anyone the coordinates to any of the locations you built. Also when entering a minecraft world you usually first start somewhere around the coordinate plane equivalent of 0 i would recommend trying to traverse to that location and (possibly) checking if your buildings and structures are there. I will link to more information on the coordinate plane in minecraft.

Hope it works, this method is worth a shot!

Coordinate information for minecraft: [Click Here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Coordinates)